# Populate lists with all possible permutations of one or all elements of a list

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

How is possible to populate lists, of fixed length, using all possible permutations of one or all elements of a list?

For instance, I want to populate lists of 3 elements containing all possible permutations of one or all numbers [1,2,3]. All ways of creating lists of length 3, with these 3 numbers, are:

`arranging = [[1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,2], [2,2,2], [1,1,3], [1,2,3], [2,2,3], [1,3,3], [2,3,3], [3,3,3]]`

To find the possible permutations of each one of this lists I would use:

`populating = [set(itertools.permutations(i, 3)) for i in arranging]`

Which is equal to:

`populating == [{(1, 1, 1)}, {(1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)}, {(1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2)}, {(2, 2, 2)}, {(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 1)}, {(3, 1, 2), (1, 3, 2), (3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 3)}, {(2, 2, 3), (3, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2)}, {(3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 1), (1, 3, 3)}, {(3, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 2)}, {(3, 3, 3)}]`

How would you create the list `arranging` (sorry for the terrible name)? Is there any other better solution?

Comment: Can you just say populating = [list(set(itertools.permutations(i, 3))) for i in arranging]?

Answer (score 2):

You want combinations with replacement:

```
iter = itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1,2,3], 3)
```

If you display that as a list you get:

```
>>> list(iter)
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), 
 (1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Note this is **not** permutations, as it contains `(1, 1, 2)` but not `(1, 2, 1)`